APKs installation failed (stuck), but still takes storage spaces afterwards
I wanna ask regarding the problem I've got after failing to install an app through an external store (TapT*p). I tried to retry it a few times until I had enough, and it happened that my storage spaces increased a lot after installation failures.
What I've been trying until now

Cleaning every cache using a disk analyzer or something like that
Rebooting my phone

But it seems the data persists and won't be gone. I think I know what I have to do... but I don't want to do a factory reset because of this matter, and my phone state is unrooted thus I can't do deeper regarding the issue.
It seems I've only seen one of the same problems in this forum, and the author says the problem was fixed in 3 days, could it be true tho? I installed a large app & it won't install but takes my storage! Now I have full storage but haven't the app?.
Anyone who has the same problem or knows how to deal with it, please tell me the way!

I have encountered the same issue trying to install a 1.5 GB game. Go to settings, apps and enable viewing system apps. see if package installer has cache. I had like 3000 MB of cache so I deleted all app data for the app (this would not affect operations anyway) and rebooted to solve the problem.
